# initialMagnification prevents imshow in loop

Tags: linux, matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matlab script consisting of a loop ending with a `pause`.
in each iteration I want to show two enlarged images. I use `imshow` with the `initialMagnification` parameter. It works as long as I only show one image. As soon as I try to draw two images, they get repainted only sporadically or if I move/resize the window.
Here is a minimal example:

```
close all
for i=1:100
    i
    A = zeros(100);
    A(i,:)= 1;
    figure(1)
    imshow(A,'initialMagnification', 500)
    figure(2)                             % without these lines, it works
    imshow(A,'initialMagnification', 500) % without these lines, it works
    pause
end
```

I am running on R2014a on Ubunut 14.04.
**Update:**
I tested it on Windows, it runs smoothly there.

Comment: What if you use drawnow after the calls to imshow?

Comment: @Benoit_11 I tried drawnow, unfortunately, It is still not working

Comment: It seems that the code above works sometimes, and sometime it hangs